# how do I create a pygame with multiple menus ?

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.6

if I click on play button on first menu it should open a menu for users to choose the levels . in the code I wrote , on clicking the play button , the computer is also assuming that I also clicked on the easy button which is placed in the same place as the play button in the level screen.It is directly going to the game loop .

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Could you add more details? What have you tried so far? What problems are you facing? See [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more help on posing the right question on SO

Comment: [Please add your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: probably you use `mouse.get_pressed()` which gives `True` when you hold button pressed - and it makes problem. Using event `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` you get `True` only when button changes state from "not-pressed" to "pressed", but not when you hold it pressed. But mostly it needs a lot changes in button, especially if you have button in one function. Example [button in many functions](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/pygame/button-using-function/main.py) or [button in class](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/pygame/button-click-cycle-color/example-class.py)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you use `mouse.get_pressed()` which gives `True` when you hold button pressed - and it makes problem. Using event `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` you get "True" only when button changes state from `"not-pressed"` to `"pressed"`, but not when you hold it pressed.

But mostly it needs a lot changes in button, especially if you have button in one function.

Example which uses class `Button`

```
import pygame

# --- constants ---

WIDTH = 320
HEIGHT = 110

FPS = 5

# --- class ---

class Button(object):

    def __init__(self, position, size, color, text):

        self.image = pygame.Surface(size)
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect((0,0), size)

        font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 32)
        text = font.render(text, True, (0,0,0))
        text_rect = text.get_rect()
        text_rect.center = self.rect.center

        self.image.blit(text, text_rect)

        # set after centering text
        self.rect.topleft = position

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def is_clicked(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                return self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos)

def stage1(screen):

    button1 = Button((5, 5), (100, 100), (0,255,0), "GO 1")
    button2 = Button((215, 5), (100, 100), (0,255,0), "EXIT")

    # - mainloop -

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    running = True

    while running:

        # - events -

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()

            if button1.is_clicked(event):
                # go to stage2
                stage2(screen)
            if button2.is_clicked(event):
                # exit
                pygame.quit()
                exit()

        # - draws -

        screen.fill((255,0,0))    
        button1.draw(screen)
        button2.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()

        # - FPS -

        clock.tick(FPS)

def stage2(screen):

    button1 = Button((5, 5), (100, 100), (255,0,0), "GO 2")
    button2 = Button((215, 5), (100, 100), (255,0,0), "BACK")

    # - mainloop -

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    running = True

    while running:

        # - events -

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()

            if button1.is_clicked(event):
                stage3(screen)
            if button2.is_clicked(event):
                return

        # - draws -

        screen.fill((0,255,0))    
        button1.draw(screen)
        button2.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()

        # - FPS -

        clock.tick(FPS)

def stage3(screen):

    button2 = Button((215, 5), (100, 100), (0,0,255), "BACK")

    # - mainloop -

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    running = True

    while running:

        # - events -

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()

            if button2.is_clicked(event):
                return

        # - draws -

        screen.fill((128,128,128))    
        button2.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()

        # - FPS -

        clock.tick(FPS)

# --- main ---

# - init -

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

# - start -

stage1(screen)

# - end -

pygame.quit()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]